# awk - if condition is met, print specific lines before and after

Tags: bash, awk, blast

Having the following `blastout.txt`:

[blastout.txt](https://pastebin.com/ycYt75nu)

I need to search all lines that contain `Identities = [>=50]` and

1. print the one line above that contains `Query=`
2. print the 5th line below

example output (only first lines shown here):

```
Query= HWI-ST863:386:C5Y8UACXX:3:1307:8061:42115 1:N:0:ACACGAAT
Sbjct  2030309  ATGACGCTCACCTTGGTGTCGATATCCTCACCTGCGGTGCCAATGCCGCTGCCCGCGGTC  2030250
Query= HWI-ST863:386:C5Y8UACXX:3:2209:19756:21341 1:N:0:ACACGAAT
Sbjct  2418742  CAGGCGTTCCGGCAGTTTGTGCTGGAAGAGGCCCGTGGCCTGGCGGAGCCTCTGCCGGCG  2418683
Query= HWI-ST863:386:C5Y8UACXX:3:1302:8580:7972 1:N:0:ACACGAAT
Sbjct  3178017  CCAGTTATGCTTGGGGCAGGTGAGCTTGTTGCCTTCCAGGGCGAGCTCGGGGATATCCGT  3178076
```

I solved `2.`:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/Identities =/ && ($3+0)>=50 {c=5}' blastout.txt
```

that was feasable for me because the structure of the file is always the same. But for the `1.` the number of lines is changing, and it can also happen that for one entry of `Query=`, there is more than one line that match the pattern.

Your help in implementing this is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/Query/{q=$0} c...; /Identities/...{print q; c=5}
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output. Don't ask/expect us to go off looking at other sites for examples as that implies you're being too lazy to come up with a concise example of your problem and want us to do the work for you of trying to understand some large dataset.

Spelled out:

```
awk '/Query/{q=$0} c&&!--c; /Identities =/ && ($3+0)>=50 {print q; c=5}' blastout.txt
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is not the full dataset, the full one has ~6 Gb. Therefore I only uploaded part of it. I was apparently not able to nail it down into some few lines, as the dataset seemed too complex for me to do that. I will now try to understand the solution you suggested. thanks again!

Comment: I came up with `awk '/Query= /{q=$0}' blastout.txt | awk 'c&&!--c;/Identities =/ && ($3+0)>=50 {print q, c=5}' blastout.txt` now, but all I get for the first awk command is `5`. What does `c...` stand for?

Comment: No, put it all in one command. `c...` stands for the part of your code that starts with `c`. I updated my answer, see the bottom.

Comment: thank you so much, awk is actually much more intuitive than I thought. just to be complete, it should be `awk '/Query= /...` instead of `awk '/Query/...`

Answer (score 1):

Well I cannot tell you how to do it with `awk`, but I can do it with `sed`.

The `blastout.sed` script is:

```
# place 'Query=' line in hold space
/^Query=/h
# If we find an Identity line
/^ Identities = \([5-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9][0-9]\)/{
# Exchange pattern with hold space (the Query= line) and print
x
p
# Exchange pattern with hold space (the Identities = line) and print
x
p
# Get the fifth line and print
n
n
n
n
n
p
}
```

Run it with the command `sed -n -f blastout.sed blastout.txt`.

Here are some results:

```
$ sed -n -f blastout.sed blastout.txt | head -12
Query= HWI-ST863:386:C5Y8UACXX:3:1307:8061:42115 1:N:0:ACACGAAT
 Identities = 100/100 (100%), Gaps = 0/100 (0%)
Sbjct  2030309  ATGACGCTCACCTTGGTGTCGATATCCTCACCTGCGGTGCCAATGCCGCTGCCCGCGGTC  2030250
Query= HWI-ST863:386:C5Y8UACXX:3:2209:19756:21341 1:N:0:ACACGAAT
 Identities = 99/100 (99%), Gaps = 0/100 (0%)
Sbjct  2418742  CAGGCGTTCCGGCAGTTTGTGCTGGAAGAGGCCCGTGGCCTGGCGGAGCCTCTGCCGGCG  2418683
Query= HWI-ST863:386:C5Y8UACXX:3:1302:8580:7972 1:N:0:ACACGAAT
 Identities = 100/100 (100%), Gaps = 0/100 (0%)
Sbjct  3178017  CCAGTTATGCTTGGGGCAGGTGAGCTTGTTGCCTTCCAGGGCGAGCTCGGGGATATCCGT  3178076
Query= HWI-ST863:386:C5Y8UACXX:3:1106:4759:9532 1:N:0:ACACGAAT
 Identities = 100/100 (100%), Gaps = 0/100 (0%)
Sbjct  32627  CGAGGCCGCGGTTTTGGACCTGGACGAGGGGAGTCGGCGTGTGAGTCTTGCGACCCTGGA  32686
```

(Corrected to print the **fifth** line down.)

Comment: thank you, also a nice one! on the side: the line starting with `Identities` is not needed.